# JS function not calling from modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a button which triggers a function from the JS for removing an entity:

```
<div type="button" class="transparentButton" ng-click="Remove(data)" title="Delete"
style="border-radius:50%;width:36px;height:36px;background-color:red;color:black;float:left;margin-left:5px;font-size:18px;" 
><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></div></div>
```

I wanted to change it the way that it, at first, asks for a confirmation and then proceeds with the delete, so made the following change when clicking the button:

```
<div type="button" class="transparentButton" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Confirm"
style="border-radius:50%;width:36px;height:36px;background-color:red;color:black;float:left;margin-left:5px;font-size:18px;" 
><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></div></div>
```

And enabled some Modal in order to ask for confirm:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Confirm" tabindex="-5" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;top:70px">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="container">
                    <form class="form-signin">
                        <h4 class="delete-title">Sure you want to Delete?</h4>
                        <br>
                        <div class="yesnolink">
                            <a class="button1" ng-click="Remove(data)" style="float:left;margin-left:80px;">Delete</a>
                            <a class="button1" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-right:100px;">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Fun starts from here, the function triggered correctly when I use the initial button, but no action when I try to call it from modal. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: In the confirmation popup you have buttons defined as <a> tag. Just why??? Could this be the issue? I recommend you to make the button from confirmation popup to be the same and then try again.

Comment: I did it with a usual button as well, but again the function is not triggered.

Comment: Well, that's strange. I assume you have this parts of HTML in the same file and you including javascript script at the end of the document?

Comment: try using $parent.Remove(data) in modal

Comment: @reillyethan not sure that it is the case. Anyways the js files are imported at the beginning.

Comment: @nlimits yeah, my bad that is not the case. Well, you can try what deoD suggested, and if it doesn't help, maybe make a jsfiddle in order to repeat the exact same bug. From my experience, trying to reproduce it usually solves the problem

Comment: @deoD tried as well, but not working =(